# ADF - Updating extended view objects

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

Is it possible to force a update of extended view objects, when the base object is updated?
As of now (Jdeveloper 11g Release 1), I have to open the query and select OK when closing the query form - in each extended view object. This forces the object to be updated.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds odd. If you change a class that is used at runtime and read from either the classpath or a library on the classpath then changes should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possibly a bug if it doesn't refresh. Try the latest version of jdeveloper from otn and to see if its an issue with your version of jdev only. If it doesnt then upgrade and if upgrade is not the option or you can still reproduce this consistently which sounds yes then go ahead and please log a bug.